# Swing ouput window like Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, console, window, output

I'm making a swing application that need the output window like Netbeans or console like Eclipse. I can add the console using Eclipse RCP, but don't know how to add output window like Netbeans. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) can be used as a simple console.